# Querying Firebase data with AngularFire2 in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

This is my firebase database structure.
I want to delete memberlist item. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.

```
let dbRef = firebase.database().ref('newaccount/' + accountId + '/memberlist');

dbRef.remove()
```

Comment: What is the issue? Can you explain more?

Comment: i want just delete the member list of particular item

Comment: give this type of response
Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}database: Databasekey: "uiduy4pzPtkhwedM60bLKx1aWzsD6H3"orderByCalled_: falseparent: Referencepath: Path {pieces_: Array(4), pieceNum_: 0}queryParams_: QueryParams {limitSet_: false, startSet_: false, startNameSet_: false, endSet_: false, endNameSet_: false, …}ref: (...)repo: Repo {repoInfo_: RepoInfo, app: FirebaseAppImpl, dataUpdateCount: 2,

Comment: Can you read this? Please put that on your question with `code` formatting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154197/discussion-between-jatin-devani-and-sampath).